# <p:selectOneMenu><f:selectItems> does not display the itemLabel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

When i use f:selectItems to display a `List<Bean>` in a view, does not display the value on itemLabel. Also, doesnt get the id on itemValue. 
I want to display only the itemLabel on selectItems.

But, show this :
ID=1, Descricao=Livro

instead of :
Livro

what am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

I have a f:selectItems as follow:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <h:outputText value="TIPO:"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{publicacaoMB.publicacao.tipo}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{tipoMB.listTipos}" var="tipo"
                                itemLabel="#{tipo.descricao}" itemValue="#{tipo.tipoId}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

And a ManagedBean :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TipoMB extends ManagedBeanBasico implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2482494734070978599L;
    @ManagedProperty(name = "tipoFacade", value = "#{tipoFacade}")
    private TipoFacade tipoFacade;
    private List<Tipo> listTipos;
    private Tipo tipo;

public List<Tipo> getListTipos() {
        try {
            listTipos = tipoFacade.getTodosTipos();
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listTipos;

    }
```

And a Facade:

```
public class TipoFacadeImpl implements TipoFacade, Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8560527136998650945L;
    @ManagedProperty(name="tipoDAO", value="#{tipoDAO}")
    private TipoDAO tipoDAO;
    private List<Tipo> listTipos;

public List<Tipo> getTodosTipos() throws DAOException {
        if(listTipos == null) {
            listTipos = tipoDAO.getTodosTipos();
        }
        return listTipos;
    }
```

And a DAO:

```
public class TipoDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements TipoDAO, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8698127647660788120L;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert sji;
    @Value("#{queries.sql03}")
    private String sql03;

public List<Tipo> getTodosTipos() throws DAOException {
        try {
            RowMapper<Tipo> mapper = getRowMapper();
            return getJdbcTemplate().query(this.sql03, mapper);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            throw new DAOException("Não há registros na tabela de tipos.");
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private RowMapper<Tipo> getRowMapper() {
        RowMapper<Tipo> mapper = new RowMapper<Tipo>() {
            public Tipo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Tipo t = new Tipo();
                t.setTipoId(rs.getInt("tipo_id"));
                t.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));

                return t;
            }
        };
        return mapper;
```

Also a web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SdiInventario</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>65535</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>smoothness</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



</web-app>
```

Comment: Just some comments: I guess the norm would be to have itemValue="#{tipo}" and then have a converter for Tipo (search for jsf converter). Also one should never have logic in a getter-method in jsf, I think you should move the code in  getListTipos() to a init()-method with @PostConstruct, and just return listTipos from the getter

Comment: In other words, the `getListTipos()` method returned a list of `Tipo` entities without the `descricao` property set? Or have you already excluded that part form being the cause? That isn't clear from the question. JSF is here just the presenter of the model. JSF can't do much if the model is already corrupted in first place.

Comment: @BalusC the property descricao is set. However the f:selectItems doesnt show the property on the itemLabel.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. So a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is welcome. In the meanwhile, have you checked the `<select>` element in the generated HTML output to exclude one and other?

Comment: @BalusC in the generated HTML the <select> is like that: <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label=" ID=1, Descricao=LIVRO"> ID=1, Descricao=LIVRO</li>

Comment: Ah, it thus doesn't seem to actually return a `List<Tipo>`? Try looping over it in plain Java like `for (Tipo tipo : tipos)`. Which `ClassCastException` do you get? That part is then likely problem in that `JdbcTemplate` thing which is in turn unrelated to JSF. You'd then need to reframe the question to focus on that part only.

Comment: @BalusC the List<Tipo> is returning. 
 All the generated HTML is like that: <select id="display:j_id_z_input" name="display:j_id_z_input"><option value="0"> ID=1, Descricao=LIVRO</option>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label=" ID=1, Descricao=LIVRO"> ID=1, Descricao=LIVRO</li>

In the p:selectOneMenu shows the List. But shows all the properties of Tipo (tipoId and descricao), instead of only the descricao.